# Some confusions about the openGL shading models for GL_FLAT and GL_SMOOTH

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I knew that there are only two shading modes in [openGL] which are GL_FLAT and GL_SMOOTH.
I just wanna know if there are ways to achieve Gouraud Shading and Phong Shading using only the above shading modes in [openGL]?

Comment: Strongly suggest you to forget about that API and use modern programmable OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are talking about is waaaay too outdated. GL_FLAT and GL_SMOOTH are modes of fixed function pipeline, which used Blinn-Phong lighting.

Both modes yield the same lighting model, but with GL_FLAT values for pixels inside a poly are not interpolated. So each polygon with GL_FLAT gets uniformly lighted and looks flat.

Answering your question, you can't get anything except Blinn-Phong with GL_SMOOTH and GL_FLAT.

> I knew that there are only two shading modes

It's not true since ~15 years ago.

At present fixed-pipeline functionality is deprecated. Please use shaders and implement any lighting you want, unless you are forced to use legacy GL by threats of violence.

Comment: I knew they were outdated but it is some requirements in our research assignment. But it seems that we can use GL_SMOOTH to achieve Gouraud Shading by simulating colour interpolation?

Comment: Why we can not achieve Phong Shading directly using these two GL functions?

Comment: @Jamin Gouraud shading seems to be a model-agnostic technique, whose point is to compute lighting only for vertices and interpolate colors, instead of interpolating normals. Lighting computation itself may be done with Phong model (dotprod of view directions) or Blinn-Phong (dotprod of poly normal and halfway normal). So if spec says it's Blinn-Phong, then you can't get Phong, as they have different formulae for light intensity.

Comment: See also the [wiki page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline): Hardware support for lighting only extended as far as the Blinn-Phong lighting model, computed per vertex and interpolated as a final light intensity.